# Cycle between 2 matplotlib plots in a QWidget

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I've got a QWidget which I'm using to host some matplotlib plots. I have multiple plots (2 at the moment, but this will increase), but only one plot is shown at a time. I have a timeout event, such that every 5 seconds the current plot is 'removed' from the Widget, and the next plot is added to the widget. This is my first experience with matplotlib plotting, so I'm unsure whether my approach (below) is correct.

Setting up the two plots:

```
#PLOT 1
Data = #inherited from another class
DataArray = #inherited from another class

DataPos = DataArray > 0
DataNeg = DataArray < 0

self.Figure1 = plt.figure('Figure1')
self.Figure1.patch.set_alpha(0)
self.Canvas1 = FigureCanvas(self.Figure1)
self.LayoutWidget.addWidget(self.Canvas1)

self.Ax1 = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, axisbg='black')
self.Ax1.bar(np.arange(len(DataArray))[DataPos], DataArray[DataPos], width=1, color='blue')
self.Ax1.bar(np.arange(len(DataArray))[DataNeg], DataArray[DataNeg], width=1, color='red')
self.Ax1.tick_params(axis='y', colors='white')
plt.title('GRAPH TIME', color='w', fontsize=30, fontname='Sans Serif', fontweight='bold'
self.Figure1.tight_layout()
plt.close() #Not sure if/why I need this line?

#PLOT 2
Radius = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Area = [1, 4, 2, 4, 6, 8]
self.Figure2 = plt.figure('Figure2')
self.Figure2.patch.set_alpha(0)
self.Canvas2 = FigureCanvas(self.Figure2)

self.Ax2 = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, axisbg='black')
self.Ax2.tick_params(axis='y', colors='white')
plt.title('GRAPH TITLE', colors='w', fontsize=30, fontname='Sans Serif', fontweight='bold')
self.Figure2.tight_layout()
plt.plot(Radius, Area, color='blue', linewidth=5)
plt.close() #Again, not sure if/why this is needed.
```

And the timeout function which changes the plot in the widget:

```
#if current plot = 1:
    self.LayoutWidget.removeWidget(self.Canvas1)
    self.LayoutWidget.addWidget(self.Canvas2)
    #This works as desired!

#elif current plot = 2:
    self.LayoutWidget.removeWidget(self.Canvas2)
    self.LayoutWidget.addWidget(self.Canvas1)
    #This doesn't work!

#Stop the timeout timer, then restart the timer, etc.
```

Is this an acceptable approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been playing with this for the last hour or so, and have achieved my desired functionality. There were a few things in my original code which needed to be changed. Here's the amended code, which works as desired.

Setting up the two plots:

```
#PLOT 1
Data = #inherited from another class
DataArray = #inherited from another class

DataPos = DataArray > 0
DataNeg = DataArray < 0

self.Figure1 = plt.figure('Figure1')
self.Figure1.patch.set_alpha(0)
self.Canvas1 = FigureCanvas(self.Figure1)
self.LayoutWidget.addWidget(self.Canvas1)

self.Ax1 = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, axisbg='black')
self.Ax1.bar(np.arange(len(DataArray))[DataPos], DataArray[DataPos], width=1, color='blue')
self.Ax1.bar(np.arange(len(DataArray))[DataNeg], DataArray[DataNeg], width=1, color='red')
self.Ax1.tick_params(axis='y', colors='white')
plt.title('GRAPH TIME', color='w', fontsize=30, fontname='Sans Serif', fontweight='bold'
self.Figure1.tight_layout()
self.Canvas1.show()

#PLOT 2
Radius = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Area = [1, 4, 2, 4, 6, 8]
self.Figure2 = plt.figure('Figure2')
self.Figure2.patch.set_alpha(0)
self.Canvas2 = FigureCanvas(self.Figure2)

self.Ax2 = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, axisbg='black')
self.Ax2.tick_params(axis='y', colors='white')
plt.title('GRAPH TITLE', colors='w', fontsize=30, fontname='Sans Serif', fontweight='bold')
self.Figure2.tight_layout()
plt.plot(Radius, Area, color='blue', linewidth=5)
```

And the timeout function:

```
#if current plot = 1:
    self.Canvas1.close()
    self.LayoutWidget.removeWidget(self.Canvas1)
    self.LayoutWidget.addWidget(self.Canvas2)
    self.Canvas2.show()

#elif current plot = 2:
    self.Canvas2.close()
    self.LayoutWidget.removeWidget(self.Canvas2)
    self.LayoutWidget.addWidget(self.Canvas1)
    self.Canvas1.show()

#Stop the timeout timer, then restart the timer, etc.
```

Simple!

Comment: I haven't tried this yet but have you considered something like QTabWidget.    You could add new tabs to contain each plot with the `addTabs()` method and cycle through the tabs programmatically with `setCurrentIndex()`  http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#details  It would also give you/the user some visual information about how many plots there are and the position in the sequence.

Comment: ... or on second thought just have 1 plot area and then in your timer just clear the axes, and re-plot the next item in the sequence.  That way you don't have a bunch of figure/canvas/axes object floating around.  Just 1 figure/canvas/axes and a several Data arrays.

Comment: I had considered both of those approaches, but settled on this approach for simplicity. I like the fact that the plot is only generated once, and then hidden/shown, as opposed to having to recalculate the plot, which often contains thousands of data points. Thanks for your input!

Comment: I'm not sure what type of stuff you are plotting or if the you can re-use the axis (all line plots? all Cartesian?) but if so you could just add a new line to the existing axes and only toggle the visible state of the lines themselves with `set_visible`.  I could see your approach getting messy and creating lots of objects  if the number of plots grows to high.  This way you only add 1 addition line object  for each plot instead of 1 Fig, 1 canvas, 1 axes, 1 line for each plot.  Just a suggestion.

Comment: This would be the perfect approach, but I'm unfortunately using a mix of line, bar, pie, etc.